# Problem with dictionary in order to class every object of that

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a dict with keys(nodes) having as values his sons. I created a class in order to get sons and father of that node, itering on the dict and saving the keys as object with those variable in another list. The problem came when i pass to a subtree that needs to be the same object of the previous node(like a son of another node), in order to have the full discendence of tree in every object of the list. When i save that obiviously it is saved as another object. How do i link those? Like a check if there's already an object of that class with that value in order to take that in a variable and work on it... maybe i'm failing the logic behind(?).

```
class Nodo():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.val = value
        self.figli = []
        self.padre = None

d_i = {'2': ['3'], '1': ['2', '4'], '5': ['6'], '7': ['8', '9', '10'], 
'10': ['12'], '8': ['11']}
nodi = []

for k,v in d_i.items():
        nodo = Nodo(k)
        nodi.append(nodo)
        for figlio in v: 
            figlio = Nodo(figlio)
            nodo.figli.append(figlio)
            figlio.padre = nodo
```

the output should be like :

```
a = '2'
a.figli = ['3']
a.padre = '1'
#all of that value should be type = Nodo
```

and so on...
but as i said i'm not adding son to the same objects every cicle.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is hard to understand your question without it.

Comment: What is Nodo? Include complete code snippet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.

Comment: i added the missing part now...

Comment: Your code produces no output..  Your variables `a c g` do not exist in the given program.

Comment: Be more specific about how you show the “expected” output and the “actual” output -e.g. by editing code to produce that output into your question. Where do a, c and g come from?

Comment: Your code is also confusing in the way it re-uses variables.  Most of all, you change the loop index `figlio` as soon as you generate each value.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you have not properly researched existing tree and node handling in Python.  In particular, you fail to check whether or not a particular family member already has an existing node.  For *every* node in the dict and *every* child, you create a new, independent node with that name.  You need your class to have a "find this node" method that will return either the existing node or a new one.

With that function in place, your main program can simply use the returned node, adding children as indicated.  Something like this:

```
class Nodo():
    roster = {}    # dict of all nodes by name

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.val = value
        self.figli = []
        self.padre = None
        Nodo.roster[value] = self

    def find(value):
        if value in Nodo.roster:   # Return the existing node.
            return Nodo.roster[value]
        else:                 # Make a new node and return that.
            return Nodo(value)

d_i = {'2': ['3'], '1': ['2', '4'], '5': ['6'], '7': ['8', '9', '10'], 
'10': ['12'], '8': ['11']}
nodi = []

for k,v in d_i.items():
        gen = Nodo(k)
        nodi.append(gen)
        for nome in v:
            figlio = Nodo.find(nome)
            gen.figli.append(figlio)
            figlio.padre = gen
```

Does that help you move toward a solution?

Comment: the roster is a class variable?

Comment: @SaltyGiampy jep

Comment: maybe `get_or_create` would be more suitable as naming for the `find` method.

Comment: Yes, there are many better names.  I left it simple, as OP is not a native English user.

Comment: @Prune might I point out that the code of your solution is broken?!

Comment: yea my explanation was not so clear, sowie.  Anyway i think u forgot to use Nodo.roster instead of roster in the methods. Now i'm trying but it looks weird because if i initialize an object it will be always added to roster... i shouldn't implement the find to the constructor?

Comment: You are welcome to encapsulate the find within the constructor.  I was trying to keep the functions separate to avoid confusion in the other direction.

Comment: @Prune you could have `__new__` return `cls.roster.get(value, super().__cls__())` then check in the `__init__` first `if value in Nodo.roster` and init only if not. but this seems like a hack as `__new__` becomes basically `get_or_create`

Comment: You could do all sorts of things.  I'm just trying to lead OP to a solution he can understand and expand.

Comment: i tried to encapsulate that but some node doesn't recognize their attributes... def __init__(self,value): /n
        if value in Nodo.roster:/n  
            self = Nodo.roster[value]/n
        else:/n
            self.val = value/n
            self.figli = []/n
            self.padre = None/n
            Nodo.roster[value] = self

Comment: @SaltyGiampy: that doesn't work because you tried to implement it within `__init__`, which is too late in the object creation.  You would need to hack that code into `__new__`, as `jojo` said.